# Haskell list range syntax

Tags: haskell

In [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) there is a sample `Enum` type:

```
data Day = Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Sunday
           deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read, Bounded, Enum)
```

but when I try to get a list of `Day`s using a range syntax without whitespace bordering value constructors I get the following error:

```
ghci> [Thursday..Sunday]

<interactive>:30:2:
    Failed to load interface for `Thursday'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

<interactive>:30:2:
    A section must be enclosed in parentheses thus: (Thursday.. Sunday)
```

When I use whitespaces everything works:

```
ghci> [Thursday .. Sunday]
[Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday]
```

What is the reason for this behavior (for example ranges for `Int`s don’t require whitespaces)?

Comment: tl;dr: `Thursday` is interpreted as module name when you use `Thursday.`

Comment: The language _enforcing_ good style, a rare enough occurrence. Not putting spaces around the `..` is **ugly**. I cringe every time I see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't actually find a rule for this in the [Haskell syntax](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/syntax-iso.html), but here's an educated guess.

The dot is also the operator that separates modules names from identifiers, as in `Prelude.id`, so the grammar would probably be ambiguous, or at least harder to parse, if `Monday..Sunday` were allowed. An exception is made for numbers, because those are special anyway; a dot may be part of a numeric literal and a module name may not be numeric literal.

Comment: Numbers don't start with an uppercase letter, so there's no ambiguity then, since a module name must start with one.